# Implement Delegate Callbacks. How do i?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, callback

I have been told to implement Delegate Callbacks.

In header file, conform the protocols: `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

How would I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.h` file, conform your class to those delegate protocols by adding `<`, your protocols that you want to conform to (comma-separated), and then a closing `>`.

Example:

```
@interface MyClass<MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

,,,

@end
```

You need to then implement the required methods in the protocols in your `.m` file.

Take a look at the required methods of these protocols in their respective documentation:

[MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate](http://developer.euro.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009669-CH1-SW3)

[UINavigationControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>{
 IBOutlet UITextView *messagetoSend;
}

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)sendInAppSMS:(id) sender;

@end


does that look right to you ?

Comment: Getting error   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:

Answer (score 0):

To Solve an error 
Getting error "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:

write following in .h file

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting error "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:

-> You've got to import "MessageUI" framework at "Build Phases" > "Link Binary With Libraries"